# ssh returned with something 'unknown'

Tags: ssh

I use ssh to run some command remotely,something like this:

```
ssh user@host 'sudo command'
```

after that, I got this line shown in the shell:

**'unknown': I need something more specific.**

what does it mean? I'm sure it's the result of the execution of the command,
should be something related to ssh itself.

Comment: What command were you trying to run?

Comment: I searched for the msg you get. You should too. maybe you're using "torque"? and maybe it needs a patch? http://osdir.com/ml/clustering.torque.user/2006-01/msg00193.html

Answer (score 1):

Its an old question without a valid response, hence answering it now.

The response - "'unknown': I need something more specific" is mostly coming from ncurses / curses library. The reason you are getting it is - there is no valid terminal at the remote.

To get rid of such issues, use -t (or -ttt) with your ssh command.

```
ssh -ttt user@host 'sudo command'
```